# Google Search Console: Continuous Decrease in Search Impressions While There is Almost No Change in Position

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search, search-engines

One of my clients has a website that is visited by tens of thousands of users per day. Google Search Console is showing continuous decrease in search impressions starting from 01-April-2018. The search impressions have decreased around 70% since then. I understand this is normal for the websites to have ups and downs in search impressions due to change in their ranking in search engines and also due to changes in search engine algorithms. But the confusing factor is that there is almost no change in search positions; rather they have improved a bit in this period. Similarly, CTR has also improved.

My question: how is it possible to have dropping search impressions (and traffic as also shown in Google Analytics) while there is a positive change in search positions / ranking and CTR?

Please note that this website is in a niche where there is no significant impact on search impressions (and traffic) by the factors like seasons, months, events, etc. as observed by us in the last six years.

Comment: Have you done any changes recently to the website?

Comment: @titico No change was made to the website structure in the last two years. The website does not use SSL and have proper redirects from example.com to www.example.com, so there are no duplicate properties or pages. 10-15 new pages are added daily to the website; other than that the website structure, protocol, URLs, etc. have remained the same for last two years.